# Unexpected native crash in WPF 4.5 .Net application

Tags: c++, wpf, dll, native

We have a unexpected, unpredictible crash that happens on our application only in  rare circonstances; Especially on virtual servers in a Citrix environment but we also had the crash on different 64 bits Windows 7 computers.

THe crash is a native Windows low level crash, it is not a .net exception there it can't be caught in a try cath nor produces us an usable stracktrace we could investigate.

It is extremly complex to reproduce the bug, therefore trying to catch and debug the process win Visual in C++ Native mode is impossible.

The error message in french unfortunately, attached to this post states : 
 APPCRASH

IN the module StackHash_3e4b

Our Google investigations pinpointed a potential crash at loading a bad 32 bits dll in a 64 bits environment. But we have no clues. The app works fine on hundred of computers/citrix servers in the différents hospitals throughout france that use it.

The two native dependencies we think that could be guilty are :

1) WPF -> If the failure comes from a bad driver for instance (
 2) Native Oracle dlls we are using for our datalayer and that we attack with the ORM Devart

Thank you for your time

---

Additional Crash From the events log:

```
Nom d’événement de problème:    APPCRASH
  Nom de l’application:    Genno.exe
  Version de l’application:    2.3.1.16
  Horodatage de l’application:    54cf4f0d
  Nom du module par défaut:    **dwrite.dll**
  Version du module par défaut:    6.1.7601.17514
  Horodateur du module par défaut:    4ce7c62f
  Code de l’exception:    c00000fd
  Décalage de l’exception:    00000000000aa4b2
  Version du système:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.16.7
  Identificateur de paramètres régionaux:    1036
  Information supplémentaire n° 1:    efc1
  Information supplémentaire n° 2:    efc1a0d5799154037d74fafb6eb0c817
  Information supplémentaire n° 3:    28da
  Information supplémentaire n° 4:    28da69bb99fe739bb215c1c1db4e55f8
```

Comment: This lacks all the neccessary information to allow investigating it...

Comment: I think the OP doesn't know how to get the information he needs to investigate it? This sounds like you need to attach WinDBG / AdPlus and wait for the crash to happen.

Comment: first off there should be an entry in the windows application event log, and as stated above the use of WinDBG is the next step investigating.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it is very hard to investigate, especially since we are unable to reproduce it locally and investigate  it.

Comment: I attach an other detailed crash we have got on this, I will see with the provider if attaching with WinDBG is something we can do.